# Codelab's webrtc complete only allows for one connection? How do I allow more?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, webrtc, p2p

I am using the code from codelab's webrtc guide, it is the complete step 7 code. I modified main a little bit, in the sense that the room is not "foo" but a value between 0 and 1 (math.random between 0 and 1). So it has a possibility of creating two different rooms. Now, I host it on localhost, open two tabs, refresh until they are both the same "room number" and then they connect. Works fine.

THEN, I open two more tabs and wait until each one has the same room number. Like, if the other ones had room number 0, then I wait until my second two tabs have room 1. BUT they still don't connect! It seems like this code doesn't allow for more than one connection and I can't figure out why. Anyone have any ideas? I'm sure it must be a simple fix, somewhere in there where you can just replace "1" with a ">0" or something.

Comment: Please include the relevant code.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/webrtc/codelab/src/c75c8e837a125441d2ee008c55348ac5a24a85d4/complete/step7/?at=master

Comment: Except, in main, make the room not equal to "foo" but make it equal to Math.floor(Math.random()*2);

Comment: I am pretty sure that the source code on allows a single peer connection per room. You would have to create a new peer connection for each new peer added.